# Sharepoint installation with existing sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, server, sharepoint-2013

I have two Servers in one network Server1 & Server2 (using HyperV).

I have installed Sql Server 2012 in Server1. Now I want to install Sharepoint 2013 in Server2 but I don't want to install SQL Server 2012 again in Server2.

My question is: 
Question 1 : Is it possible to install in above method.
Question 2 : After installation, Is it possible to access Sharepoint 2013 with Sql Server 2012 in different Server.